# Indefinite integral that cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have the following **indefinite** integral which I cannot evaluate by integration by part, change of variable etc.

$$\int\frac{1}{y}e^{-(y-A)^2}dy$$

The output of Wolfram Alpha is in the [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%281%2Fy+*+e%5E%28-%28y-A%29%5E2%29%2C+y%29). Note that A is a constant parameter.

Comment: Your WA input is different than the expression in the question.

Comment: @MikeMiller I have it corrected.

Comment: I would say, expand the $\frac{1}{y}e^{-(y-A)^2}$ to series and integrate term by term.

Comment: @georg I already thought of that, but it is not that convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int\dfrac{e^{-(y-A)^2}}{y}dy$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(y-A)^{2n}}{n!y}dy$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^nC_k^{2n}(-1)^{2n-k}A^{2n-k}y^k}{n!y}dy$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(2n)!A^{2n-k}y^{k-1}}{n!k!(2n-k)!}dy$

$=\int\left(\dfrac{1}{y}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(2n)!A^{2n-k}y^{k-1}}{n!k!(2n-k)!}\right)dy$

$=\int\left(\dfrac{1}{y}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nA^{2n}}{n!y}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(2n)!A^{2n-k}y^{k-1}}{n!k!(2n-k)!}\right)dy$

$=\int\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nA^{2n}}{n!y}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(2n)!A^{2n-k}y^{k-1}}{n!k!(2n-k)!}\right)dy$

$=\int\left(\dfrac{e^{-A^2}}{y}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(2n)!A^{2n-k}y^{k-1}}{n!k!(2n-k)!}\right)dy$

$=e^{-A^2}\ln y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}(2n)!A^{2n-k}y^k}{n!k!k(2n-k)!}+C$